OpenAPI Parser (Light-4J) not working on "oneOf" criteria
Following is the schema.
Example 1)
components:
  schemas:
    GroupHeader114: <-- clause 1
      type: object
      properties:
        Authstn:
          type: object
          oneOf:
            - type: object
              properties:
                Cd:
                  type: string
                  enum:
                    - AUTH
                    - FDET
            - type: object
              properties:
                Prtry:
                  type: string
                  enum:
                    - ABC
                    - DDD

Payload:
{
       “GroupHeader114”: {
               “Authstn”: {
                    “Cd”: “AUTH”,
                    “Prtry”: “DDD”
               }
        }
}

Results: Validation passed when it should not since it meets criteria of both schema. There seems to be bugs in the parser or validator.
Example 2)
components:
  schemas:
    GroupHeader114: <-- clause 1
      type: object
      properties:
        GroupHeader114:
          type: object
          properties:
            Authstn:
              type: array
              maxItems: 2
              items:
                 $ref: '#.components/schemas/Authorisation1Choice'

    Authorisation1Choice:
      oneOf:
        - $ref '#components/schemas/AuthorisationCodeCd'
        - $ref '#components/schemas/Max128TextPrtry'

    Max128Text:
      type: string
      minLength: 1
      maxLength: 128

    Max128TextPrtry:
      type: object
      properties:
        Prtry:
          $ref: '#components/schemas/Max128Text'

    Authorisation1Code:
      type: string
      enum:
        - AUTH
        - FDET
        - FSUM
        - ILEV

    Authorisation1CodeCd:
     type: object
     properties:
       Cd:
         $ref: '#components/schemas/Authorisation1Code'

Payload:
{   
       “GroupHeader114”: {   
               “Authstn”: [   
              {   
                    “Cd”: “AUTH”   
               }   
        }   
}   

I am getting schema validation error saying requestBody.GroupHeader114.Authstn[0]: should be valid to one and only one of the schemas.
Appreciate any help.
Tx
ps: Light-4J - 2.0.10

You have quite a few issues with your syntax.  All references within the same schema must begin with an anchor(#) pointing to the root of the document and followed by a forward slash(/).
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: my api
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  '/some_endpoint':
    get:
      description: my api service
      responses:
        '200':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/GroupHeader114Response'
components:
  responses:
    GroupHeader114Response:
      description: OK
      content:
        'application/json':
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/GroupHeader114'
          examples:
            GroupHeader114_Authorisation1CodeCd_Example:
              $ref: '#/components/examples/GroupHeader114_Authorisation1CodeCd_Example'
            GroupHeader114_Max128TextPrtry_Example:
              $ref: '#/components/examples/GroupHeader114_Max128TextPrtry_Example'
  examples:
    GroupHeader114_Authorisation1CodeCd_Example:
      summary: my example response
      value: { "GroupHeader114": { "Authstn": [ { "Cd": "AUTH" } ] } }
    GroupHeader114_Max128TextPrtry_Example:
      summary: my example response
      value: { "GroupHeader114": { "Authstn": [ { "Prtry": "AUTH" } ] } }
  schemas:
    GroupHeader114:
      type: object
      properties:
        GroupHeader114:
          type: object
          properties:
            Authstn:
              type: array
              maxItems: 2
              items:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Authorisation1Choice'
    Authorisation1Choice:
      oneOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Authorisation1CodeCd'
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Max128TextPrtry'

    Max128Text:
      type: string
      minLength: 1
      maxLength: 128

    Max128TextPrtry:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: false
      properties:
        Prtry:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Max128Text'

    Authorisation1Code:
      type: string
      enum:
      - AUTH
      - FDET
      - FSUM
      - ILEV
    Authorisation1CodeCd:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: false
      properties:
        Cd:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Authorisation1Code'

I'm not clear on the last request. Currently, the schema only allows one or the other, not both.

should have either object Authorisation1Code or Max128Text and both.


Thanks Jeremy for all your help! Got it. What can we do without guys like you! Thanks

regarding the edit you made, the reason you can have { "GroupHeader114": { "Authstn": [ { "Cd": "AUTH" }. { "Prtry": "testing" } ] } } is because the Authstn is an array and each array index can have oneOf the schemas defined. Are you sure you want the Authstn to be an array or is an object sufficient?

It's a similar situation with example2. The mapping key entry in schemas is only an identifier of that schema. As you can see, it can be labeled anything, GroupHeader114 or A or B or Yap, the schema defined inside of that mapping entry is what the validation uses against the data instance.
components:
  schemas:
    GroupHeader114:
      oneOf: 
      - $ref '#components/schemas/A'
    A:
     type: object
     properties:
       Cd:
         type: string
         enum:
           - AUTH
           - FDET

If you're looking at the ref as a location identifier, it's pointing to the A schema defined in the components/schemas map.
Your data instance would not be
{
  "A": {
    "Cd": "AUTH"
  }
}

It would only be this because the schema definition is the contents of that key.
{
  "Cd": "AUTH"
}


if you look at the revised example 2) i want oneof at the Authorisation1Choice. How do i do that?

Basically the array Authstn .. should have either object Authorisation1Code or Max128Text and both.  How do i achieve this?

Your schema is missing the top level node.
components:
  schemas:
    GroupHeader114: # <-- this is the mapping key for the schema, not the top level json node. 
      type: object
      properties:
        GroupHeader114:
          type: object
          properties:
            Authstn:
              type: object
              oneOf:
                - type: object
                  properties:
                    Cd:
                      type: string
                      enum:
                        - AUTH
                        - FDET
                - type: object
                  properties:
                    Prtry:
                      type: string
                      enum:
                        - ABC
                        - DDD


the reason it was not flagging an error is because GroupHeader114 was not validated. It was ignored.
EDIT:
more explanation:
in OpenAPI context, the components/schemas is a map of entries.  The mapping key for the schema you defined is GroupHeader114, but that keyword is not part of the actual schema in the way you are expecting, it's just a pointer to that particular schema.
If your data instance was this, it would work the way you expect.
{
  "Authstn": {
    "Cd": "AUTH",
    "Prtry": "DDD"
  }
}


Thanks. I am still confused. I have edited my original schema added the word clause 1). Isn't the clause 1) indicates the schema key as it is directly below the Schema definition? Only difference is yours is like a wrapper with the same name GroupHeader114. Still confused :O(. Been cracking my brain last 2 days and to no avail .. :O(

i tried to explain more in the edit

Thanks. Let me digest more. I have added example 2) .. which is the original schema i had but which i couldn't figure out why it's not working. This example uses $ref. Using this way example 2), is there anything i need to change based on the original payload in order to make it work? Probably then with both examples i hope to see more clearly.

Sorry i have revised example 2). I have added more info on example 2). Not sure why the results throwing error. Can you explain please?
